# How do i paint each point i click on in a different color?

Tags: c#

This is the code of mouse down where i click on the points:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
      label1.Text = e.X.ToString();
      label2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
      label1.Visible = true;
      label2.Visible = true;
      label3.Visible = true;
      label4.Visible = true;
      // find the index that is closest to the current mouse location
      MinDist = float.MaxValue;

      for (idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx)
      {
         float dx = Point_X[idx] - e.X;
         float dy = Point_Y[idx] - e.Y;
         float dist = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

         if (dist < MinDist)
         {
            MinDist = dist;
            selectedIndex = idx;
         }
      }

      if (MinDist < 5)
      {
         mouseMove = true;
         OriginalX = Point_X[(int)selectedIndex];
         OriginalY = Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex];

         if (cyclicSelectedIndex.Count() == 2)
         {
            cyclicSelectedIndex[currentCyclicIndex] = (int)selectedIndex;
            currentCyclicIndex++;
            if (currentCyclicIndex > 1)
            {
               currentCyclicIndex = 0;
            }
            if ((cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                (cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == -1) || (cyclicSelectedIndex[1] == -1))
            {
               button2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
               button2.Enabled = true;
            }

            label13.Text = selectedIndex.ToString();
            label13.Visible = true;
            label14.Visible = true;

            listView1.Items.Add(selectedIndex.ToString()).EnsureVisible();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And this is the paint event in the first FOR LOOP i draw the points in the second FOR LOOP i draw the lines between the points.

I want that if i click on one point it will be blue and if i click on second point it will be yellow. Now when i create the points they are red.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Point connectionPointStart;
   Point connectionPointEnd;
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;
   g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
   Pen p = new Pen(brush);
   for (int idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx)
   {
      Point dPoint = new Point((int)Point_X[idx], (int)Point_Y[idx]);
      dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
      dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
      g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < connectionStart.Count; i++)
   {
      int startIndex = connectionStart[i];
      int endIndex = connectionEnd[i];

      connectionPointStart = new Point(
         (int)Point_X[startIndex], (int)Point_Y[startIndex]);
      connectionPointEnd = new Point(
         (int)Point_X[endIndex], (int)Point_Y[endIndex]);
      p.Width = 4;
      g.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about your point (isn't that solve with a simple count?).. but you should be disposing pen, brushes and things like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the brush that you use to draw each point.  Here's a simple solution.

First, add another variable to your class called previouslySelectedIndex of type int, and initialize it with -1.  Then, inside your Mouse Down event, add the line shown below:

```
     ...
     if (dist < MinDist)
     {
        MinDist = dist;
        previouslySelectedIndex = selectedIndex  // <--- Add this line
        selectedIndex = idx;
     }
     ...
```

Now, add the section noted below in the correct place inside the Paint Event handler:

```
   ...
   Brush brush = Brushes.Red;  // <-Change the type from SolidBrush to Brush, which is more general
   ...
   for (int idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx)
   {
      ...

      // START OF NEW CODE

      brush = Brushes.Red;  // <-- This line was not in my original solution.

      if (idx==selectedIndex)  // <-- Add all this code
          brush = Brushes.Blue; 
      else if(idx==previouslySelectedIndex) 
          brush = Brushes.Yellow;

      // END OF NEW CODE

      g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
   }
   ...
```

Comment: Cant make brush = Brushes since im getting error cannot convert brush to solidbrush

Comment: Ok i did:  brush = (SolidBrush) Brushes.Yellow; and did the code in the mouse down event too. But when i run the program and add new points they are already in blue before i click on them. I want them to be as before in Red and only when i click on a point it will be blue and the second allways the second click will be yellow. Now when i add a point its blue when i click on it its yellow. But i want that when i add a point it will be Red click it will be blue other point i click is yellow another point i click blue seocnd one yellow but when i add new point they will be allways Red.

Comment: @user1196715: Please check the updated code.  Instead of casting to solid brush, change the type of the variable brush as I show above.  That simplifies your syntax and makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @user1196715:  I apologize for the bug that you found in the solution.  You can fix it easily by simply adding the new line in the code:  brush = Brushes.Red;  Let me know if the solution still does not work or if you don't understand why I did what I did.

Comment: @user1196715:  Clarification: Add the new line in the code, "brush = Brushes.Red;" at the start of every iteration of the loop.  What happens is that you have to reset the color of the brush on every iteration.  Otherwise, if one point changes the color of the brush, other points will be drawn with the incorrect color.